# Insert data to the controls in one windows application from another application

Tags: c#, .net, automation, autoit, spy++

I am working on a windows application and I want to insert some data to the controls in another windows application from my application. I think it's possible using **spy++** or **AutoIt.**

But on searching I found only code like clicking a button in another application from one application.

What I need is,

I have **3** textboxes in **WindowsApp_1** and I need to fill these from the value sending from **WindowsApp_2**. Could you please give me a sample code to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are intending to work on your application, I suggest working on it, instead of abusing stackoverflow

Asking for sample code in the way like you did, suggests, that you wont be able to do what you want yourself, even if samplecode is provided.

I shall give some hints, though:

1. Read the documentation of AutoIt
2. Begin with learning how to identify a Window from your App 1

   # for instance:

   WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad")
3. Elaborate on how to get the desired text from App 1
4. Paste the ill gotten text with

   ControlSetText($app2, "", "Edit1", "This is some text")

https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/windowsbasic.htm